# using tar showing, "No Such file or directory"

Tags: 14.04, tar

[I have a .gz file on Downloads directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f99Hr.png)

But when I try to run it using

```
tar zxvf jre-8u151-linux-i586
```

I get
tar (child): jre-8u151-linux-i586: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now
tar: Child returned status 2

What is wrong? The name and place matches prefectly.

Comment: is your file named "jre-8u151-linux-i586"  (without quotes), as the system is reporting there is no file or directory of that name.  if `.gz` was part of the filename it must be provided as it IS part of the filename.

Comment: Also, if the file is just `foo.gz`, as opposed to `foo.tar.gz`, then you should use `gunzip`, not `tar`.

Comment: If the intention REALLY is  to `run` it, then tar and/or gunzip is  not the solution. tar creates and extracts archive files, gzip/gunzip compresses files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the file extension. The correct command is:

```
tar zxvf jre-8u151-linux-i586.tar.gz
```